# Why does the public static void main method not automatically run in an instantiated class?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I understand the point of `public static void main` in my starting class - to have code which is executed when the program is run.

Some articles I read online state that any class can have a main class. I created a second class which is called from the first class and created an instance of it, but the code in the second classes main method doesn't run. Am I misunderstanding how this method works in a class other than the primary class?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aClass newClass = new aClass();

    }
}
```

```
public class aClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: It just isn't. The `main` method is run either when you call it explicitly (e.g. `aClass.main(new String[0]);`), or when you tell the JVM to start and run it. A *constructor* would be run when a new instance of the class is created, though.

Comment: I am sure about this, but you cannot have more than 2 main method.. it has to be one.. @Andy Turner  but don't we have to have 1 entry??

Comment: If we start a java program, we start it by running a `.class`-file explicitly. This class has to include a `main`-method, otherwise the program start will fail. It is this class's and only this class's `main`-method that starts the program. If we run a `jar`-file, we either explicitly state the entry class (i.e. the class containing the `main`-method) or the entry class is defined in the meta-information of the jar.

Comment: @HannahLee that's not true at all. You can have as many as you like.

Comment: @HannahLee this is why you have to tell the JVM which class to run explicitly: it doesn't know what class you want it to start at, so you specify it. You can only define one `main` method in a given class, but you can put a `main` in any class in which you can define a static method. You give the JVM the name of the class, and it invokes the `main` method in that class.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter not any. An anonymous class couldn't; nor a local class, nor an inner class. And I don't think an annotation could either. Like I said: "in any class in which you can define a static method".

Comment: @AndyTurner: true. Any class that allows static methods can have one.

Comment: I usually create a main method for any class that I need to test.

Comment: Off topic... @NomadMaker You should not. And all classes -at least those having methods - need to be tested. Prefarably directly or indirectly if covered well. You should not bloat your code with stuff that does not belong there like test code. Instead use some testing framework like JUnit or so.

Answer (score 2):

It’s true that “any class can have a main class”. But only *one* `main` method is run, regardless of how many classes have one.

And which `main` method is run depends on the designated entry point of your application, i.e. what you explicitly indicate as the entry point when running your code via `java name.of.class`, or whatever your JAR manifest indicates as being the entry point.

Conversely, you can provide a class with a static initialisation block. This block will be run once, the first time the class is loaded:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new aClass();
        new aClass();
    }
}

public class aClass{
    static {
        // Run only once!
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

This code will run even when you don’t *instantiate* your class but, say, call a static method on it. But if nothing in your code ever refers to `aClass` at all, its static initialiser will *not* be run.

Answer (score 1):

The `main` method is called on one class by the JVM (unless you call it explicitly, of course).

If you want the code to be called when you instantiate `aClass`, you need to move the code to the constructor:

```java
public class aClass{
    public aClass() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

or, of course, call `aClass.main` explicitly:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aClass.main(args);
    }
}
```